# Making a filtered list with list comprehension not working

Tags: python, syntax, list-comprehension

Basically, given a list l of letters, i wanted to filter a list of letters to include only one instance of said letters in a new list:

```
l2 = []
for i in l:
    if i not in l2:
        l2.append()
```

And i wanted to use list comprehension, so i wrote:

```
l2 = [i for i in l if i not in l2]
```

But it returns me an empty l2. I'm just starting to learn how to use list comprehension and i'm kinda tired so i can't see where or if i'm doing wrong :(

Comment: I got an l2 with ALL elements, not empty

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Comment: How do you reward people who helped you? (I'm a total beginner with Stack too xD)

Comment: There is a green tick next to the answer, you can accept only one, the best to your eyes. You can also vote up (is you can enough reputation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list comprehension will not be working in this case as it works on a saved state of variable.
So, earlier l2 was blank and that state would be considered in comprehending.
Hence, the output would contain all the elements.
What i could notice is you were trying to get unique elements of 'l'.

Either you can use,

```
l2 = set(l) # if rlist is required you can type cast it back to list like, l2 = list(set(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

The list-comprehension here can't work, as `l2` is updated only when the all list-comprehension stuff is done, there no idea of list-comp intermediate state

What you want is just a unique instance of each letter, in other words : a `set`

```
l2 = set(l)
l2 = list(set(l)) # if you really want a list at the end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your list comprehension is that it relies on the list l2, which itself is the target of the list comprehension.

Sometimes a list comprehension is not the best way to go, even though it is a nice tool.

For your purpose it is best to convert list l to a set (which does not have duplicates) and then convert back to a list, which can be assigned to your list l2:

```
l2 = list(set(l))
```